# Having trouble with Rails Routing after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I'm trying to make a form that would allow users to comment on specific posts. Im currently having trouble after the submit button is clicked. The entry does get put into the database, however it looks like im experiencing some routing problems.

Here is the URL I get redirected to:
"localhost:3000/groups/13/posts/62/comments"

I get the following error after submission:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups"}

I ran rake routes to find this:

> ```
>          group GET    /groups/:id(.:format)           groups#show
> ```

Here is my comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].merge({:user_id => current_user.id}))
    redirect_to :action => :show, :controller => :groups
  end
end
```

Here is my form for the comment:

```
                    <%= form_for([post.group, post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
                      <p>
                        <%= f.label :comment %><br />
                        <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => 3, :cols => 55 %>
                      </p>
                      <p>
                        <%= f.submit %>
                      </p>
                    <% end %>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be wrong? Why is it redirecting to the url "localhost:3000/groups/13/posts/62/comments"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html

    def create
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment]) do |comment|
            comment.user = current_user # user_id shouldn't be an attr_accessible
        end
        respond_with @comment, location: group_path(@post.group)
    end
```

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"groups", :id=>nil}

Comment: Sorry, it was `@post.group` instead of `@group`.